# How do I mock get_adjacent_post for testing

Tags: unit-tests

I'm trying to mock `get_adjacent_post` for unit testing but I'm not sure how to mock global function in PHPUnit

```
    $badCode = $this->getMockBuilder('get_adjacent_post')
        ->setMethods(array('somthing'))
        ->getMock();
```

Here's what I got so far which obviously doesn't work.

And here's how I use it in production code.

```
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'topic' );
```

Comment: Although interesting, this isn't a question specific to WordPress. (But see: http://marcelog.github.io/articles/php_mock_global_functions_for_unit_tests_with_phpunit.html)

Comment: Come on, let us not be petty and not close it! After all, this is a interesting and very much development related question.

Comment: But get_adjacent_post is WordPress?

Answer (score 4):

I used `WP_Mock` for a long time, until I built [Brain Monkey](http://giuseppe-mazzapica.github.io/BrainMonkey/) to overcome some problems I found working with it.

Using *Brain Monkey* you can:

```
use Brain\Monkey\Functions;

Functions::when('get_adjacent_post')->alias(function() {
  // mock here...
});
```

or

```
Functions::expect('get_adjacent_post')
  ->atLeast()
  ->once()
  ->with( true, '', true, 'topic' )
  ->andReturnUsing(function( $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $previous ) {
     // mock here
  });
```

This latter syntax comes from [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery).

*Brain Monkey*, just like *WP_Mock*, has an API to also mock WordPress hooks.

Comment: I've never used `WP_Mock` myself (yet, anyway), but I'm curious what problems specifically you found that caused you to write Brain Monkey. I'm sure that others would find that to be useful information as well!

Comment: @J.D. this https://github.com/10up/wp_mock/issues/12 was the biggest. There were minor ones. Moreover, `WP_Mock` is using a very old PHPUnit version that forced me to do so, but I really wanted to use newer versions. Finally, I found Mockery syntax much more expressive than the array-based version used by WP_Mock. And seems that even 10up is, at least thinking, to use Brain Mockey to restructure WP_Mock see https://github.com/10up/wp_mock/issues/26.

Comment: I was wondering if I could mock this purely using Mockery?

Comment: And I get this error while running the code Call to undefined function Patchwork\replace() even though I have installed both BrainMonkey and Patchwork using composer.

Comment: @toy Mockery does not mock functions. Brain Monkey is just a "bridge" between Patchwork and Mockery. Regarding your error, are you requiring Composer autoload file?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [WP_Mock](https://github.com/10up/wp_mock):

> WP_Mock is an API mocking framework, built and maintained by 10up for the purpose of making it possible to properly unit test within WordPress.

From [an example there](https://github.com/10up/wp_mock#using-wp_mock), you'd mock `get_permalink()` like this:

```
    \WP_Mock::wpFunction( 'get_permalink', array(
        'args' => 42,
        'times' => 1,
        'return' => 'http://example.com/foo'
    ) );
```